# How to do a fadeOut Animation with Angular Animation in mat-tree before the tree's datasource changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

I couldn't find any source so far that could help me with my specific problem, therefore I am hoping to find some help here. It's quite a lot to read, therefore I am thankful for any hint.

---

I have a mat-tree list (from Angular Material) where I can't use the ":leave" to animate a fadeOut, due to the whole list being loaded newly after a change happens. 
Here is some code to explain:
Once I get new data, I call subscribe on my **dataSource**:

```
this.dataSource._flattenedData.subscribe(value => {
  this.childNodesToAnimateFadeIn = [];
  this.childNodesToAnimateFadeOut = [];
  this.getNewListItems(this.previousStatusOfList, value);
  this.previousStatusOfList = value;
});
```

I use **getNewListItems()** to decide which elements of the **mat-tree** have to fade in and which to fade out:

```
    getNewListItems(oldStatusOfList: FileFlatNode[], newStatusOfList: FileFlatNode[]) {
        /... logic is happening here ... /
        this.childNodesToAnimateFadeIn = newItems;
        this.childNodesToAnimateFadeOut = deletedItems;
      }
```

Here is a shortened Version of my **mat-tree**:

```
<mat-tree #tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node [@simpleFade]="getAnimationState(node)">
    {{text}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node [@simpleFade]="getAnimationState(node)">
    <button mat-button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle (click)="toggleNode(node)">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{text}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

**getAnimationState()** is telling each tree-element which animation to do, like:

```
  getAnimationState(node: FileFlatNode): string {
    if (this.childNodesToAnimateFadeIn.includes(nodeId)) {
      return 'expand';
    } else if (this.childNodesToAnimateFadeOut.includes(nodeId)) {
      return 'collapse';
    }
  }
```

And in my component I tell how the **simpleFade Animation** should be done:

```
 animations: [
    trigger('simpleFade', [
      transition('*=>expand', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(2000)
      ]),
      transition('*=>collapse', [
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate(3000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])]
```

Now this happens:
I get a new **dataSource._flattenedData**. I am able to detect which list elements are new and so I fill **childNodesToAnimateFadeIn**. Like that, the fade-in-animation (***=>expand**) is working fine.

But, when I get new **dataSource._flattenedData** with previous items missing, I am able to detect them and add them to **childNodesToAnimateFadeOut**. But, unlike the fadeInAnimation, the fadeOutAnimation doesn't work. The Items disappear, before the fade-out-animation (***=>collapse**) could start.

---

Important note: I am not trying to fade in and out by using the toggle-button of mat-tree, that is working already. I want to find out how I can do a fade-out-animation if:

1. There was a list before.
2. I get a **whole new** list which is **replaced** with the old list.
3. I detect which elements of the newly loaded list are missing now.
4. I give every single list-element the right animation-state. That means: The list-items which are missing in the new list, get the fade-out animation-state.

---

Note2: If you wonder what would happen if I replace

```
transition('*=>collapse', [
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate(3000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
```

with

```
transition(':leave', [
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate(3000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
```

My whole list begins to fade out, instead of just specific list-items.